# Barchart show value to print

Tags: chart.js

i have the following bar chart and tooltip showing info value

```
var chartData = {
    labels: ["Chevrolet", "Volkswagen", "Fiat", "Ford", "Renault", "Toyota"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#FFB6C1",
            strokeColor: "#FF1493",
            data: [87, 80, 56, 50, 18, 78]
        }
    ]
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(chartData, {    
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cide10/sk2vm8tL/16/)

I would like to print this graphic but the tooltip values will not print. So how can I show the values at the top of the bar chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the bars onAnimationComplete function and display the values

```
showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
            });
        })
    }
```

look in my full [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/p5tw3kae/)

Comment: oh buddy! so simple! im learning to work with chartsjs, thank you very much!

Comment: We are here to help! :)